Can't fetch the next page link utilizing the CSS selector within the apps script
I'm trying to scrape the next page link from this webpage using css selector within apps script, but I always get undefined as a result, even when my defined selector is right.
function fetchInformation() {
  const Url = 'https://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si/1/window/Vancouver+BC';
  const userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like  Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36';

  var getOptions = {
    'method': 'GET',
    'headers' : {
       'User-Agent': userAgent
     },
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(Url, getOptions);
  console.log(response.getResponseCode())
  var $ = Cheerio.load(response.getContentText());
  var nextPage = $("a[data-analytics*='load_more'].pageButton").first().attr('href');
  console.log(nextPage);

}

Python script built upon the requests module:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si/1/window/Vancouver+BC'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)
    res = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    print(soup.select_one("a[data-analytics*='load_more'].pageButton")['href'])

Output:
/search/si/2/window/Vancouver+BC

How can I get the next page link using the CSS selector within the script?

That selector looks right but expect them to block you. You can try something like zenrows api with GAS to avoid that.

For whatever reason, the selector you've chosen isn't available in the response returned to GAS. The server apparently serves up different versions of the site depending on whether you're using Python/Node on the one hand, or GAS on the other.
I'm not sure what makes GAS requests special, but GAS is pretty unusual in a number of respects, so it doesn't come as a surprise. I'm not super familiar with GAS, just get pulled into it here and there for various web scraping requests, so maybe a GAS expert can explain why it's receiving a different response than a standard Node/Python script.
In any case, I used DriveApp.createFile("test.html", response.getContentText()); to dump the response HTML to file to circumvent log truncation. From that, I noticed that the load_more substring wasn't present, but [data-ajaxpage] was, so I used that:
function myFunction() { // default GAS function name
  const url = "https://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si/1/window/Vancouver+BC";
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  // DriveApp.createFile("test.html", response.getContentText()); // to debug
  const $ = Cheerio.load(response.getContentText());
  const nextPage = $("[data-ajaxpage]").first().attr("href");
  console.log(nextPage);
}

That said, the pattern appears to be:

https://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si/0/window/Vancouver+BC
https://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si/1/window/Vancouver+BC
https://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si/2/window/Vancouver+BC
...

So rather than dealing with scraping hrefs, you could just use a loop and insert ${i} into each URL:
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  const url = `https://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si/${i}/window/Vancouver+BC`;
  // make your request with `url` and scrape
}

I picked 10 arbitrarily, but you can loop as long as you want, and if the request returns a 404 or no data results (depending on the site's specific behavior) then you're at the end.

The script still fetches the result as undefined. The element is available in the page source, and the selector can locate the next page when I use it in python.

I don't think that's accurate. Visit view-source:https://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si/1/window/Vancouver+BC in your browser and search for "load_more" and you'll see it's only available in the element I shared here. view-source: corresponds to what fetches/requests return. Can you share your Python code? You're probably using the requests library, which will return the same thing as fetch. As my answer indicates, though, you don't even need this element. Just plug ${i} into the URL to navigate each page.

You can also use curl https://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si/1/window/Vancouver+BC | grep load_more to see where that element is in the static HTML.

I've included the Python script in my post. Please check out the edit.

Ah, I see, your selector is basically the same as mine since you're using *=. Both access the same element. My mistake. I'm not sure why UrlFetch isn't working, but you might not want to mute exceptions. Anyway, since this isn't necessary, can you respond to my suggestion to "Just plug ${i} into the URL to navigate each page"? Seems like an xy problem--you're pursuing a more difficult way to do something when there's a much more direct solution, without a clear reason for not using the simple approach.

I know your suggestion will work without any issues, but at times, I face difficulties scraping different fields using the CSS selector within the apps script as opposed to Python. This is one such case, and I'm very curious to know the reason.

OK, I've updated my answer. Does it work for you?

It works flawlessly. The strangest thing is that data-ajaxpage is not available in the page source.
